# How to put a random number into an array then a text file

Tags: c++, arrays, text, random, void

So what I am trying to do is put a random number generator from one through ten into an array that has 50 elements and then put that into a text file. My problem is that the code I have written for the code and generator has an error and I can't wrap my head around how to get it into a text file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

void menu();
string createFile();
void displayNumTotalAverage(string);
void displaySortedNums();
void SearchNum();
void displayLargestNum();
void appendRandomNum(string);
void exit();
void CreateFile();
void printFunc(int[]);
void fillFunc(int[]);

int main()
{
    menu();
    string FileName;
    //createFile();
    //makeRandomNum();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
void menu()
{
    int choice;
    string FileName;
    do
    {

        //program output 
        cout << "** MENU **" << endl << endl;

        cout << "Curret Data File: " << endl << endl;

        cout << "(1) Select / create data file (.txt file extention will be added automaticly)" << endl;
        cout << "(2) Display all numbers, total and average" << endl;
        cout << "(3) Display all numbers sorted" << endl;
        cout << "(4) search for a number and display how many times it occurs" << endl;
        cout << "(5) display the largest number" << endl;
        cout << "(6) Append a random number(s)" << endl;
        cout << "(7) Exit the program" << endl << endl;

        //user input
        cout << "Menu Choice: ";
        cin >> choice;

        while (choice > 7 || choice < 1)
        {
            cout << "Menu Choice: ";
            cin >> choice;
        }

        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            cout << "Choice 1";
            createFile();
            break;

        case 2:
            cout << "Choice 2";
            displayNumTotalAverage(FileName.c_str());
            break;

        case 3:
            cout << "Choice 3";
            break;

        case 4:
            cout << "Choice 4";
            break;

        case 5:
            cout << "Choice 5";
            break;

        case 6:
            cout << "Choice 6";
            appendRandomNum(FileName.c_str());
            break;

        }


    } while (choice != 7);


}

string createFile()<----------------------------------------------------(this)
{
    cout << "Create File - Option 1" << endl;
    string FileName;
    ifstream inFile;
    cout << "Name of data file: ";
    cin >> FileName;
    FileName = "C:\\Users\Wizard\Libraries\Documents\Final Project" + FileName;
    inFile.open(FileName + ".txt");
    if (inFile)
    {
        cout << FileName;
    }
    else
        cout << "File not found, creating file.";

    system("PAUSE");
    return FileName;
}

void displayNumTotalAverage(string FileName)
{
    ifstream inFile;
    cout << "Display Number Total Average - Option 2" << endl << endl << endl;
    inFile.open("C:\\Users\Wizard\Libraries\Documents\Final Project" + FileName + ".txt");
    int num;
    int total;
    cout << "Display Number Total Average function" << FileName;
    double average;
    bool containsNum = false;
    inFile.open(FileName + ".txt");
    if (inFile)
    {
        while (inFile >> num)
        {
            cout << num << endl;
        }
        inFile.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Error opening file" << FileName << "." << endl;
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return;
}

void displaySortedNums()
{
    cout << "I AM THE displaySortedNums Function - Option 3" << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return;
}

void searchNum()
{
    cout << " I am the searchNum function - option 4" << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return;
}

void displayLargestNum()
{
    cout << "I am the displayLargestNum Function - option 5" << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return;

}

void appendRandomNum(string FileName)
{
    cout << "i am in the appendRandomNum function - option 6" << endl;
    int num = 0;
    int count = 0;
    ofstream outFile;
    outFile.open(FileName + ".txt", ios::app);
    cout << "How many random numbers: ";
    cin >> count;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        outFile << rand() % 10 << endl;
    outFile.close();
    cout << endl << "Number(s) Added" << endl << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return;
}

void exit()
{
    cout << " I am the exit function - option 7" << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return;
}

void CreateFile()<-----------(and this)
{
    int random[50]; //Random Numbers

        srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
        fillFunc(random);
        printFunc(random);



        return;

}

void fillFunc(int arr[])
{
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
                arr[i] = 1 + rand() % 10;

        }

}

void printFunc(int arr[])
{
    ofstream fout("C:\\Users\Wizard\Libraries\Documents\Final Project");
    if (fout.is_open()){
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            fout << arr[i] << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exatly is your problem?

Comment: Try testing the code pieces separately - first make sure that your generator is working (that the array is not all zeros - to make that happen you need to pass the array pointer so it can be mutable), THEN try to make the array save to a text file.

Comment: well here i the problem the error is under the 0 in return and says error C2562: 'CreateFile' : 'void' function returning a value c:\users\wizard\documents\flash drive\final project\final project\source.cpp 54 1 Final Project

Comment: ok i made some changes based on the suggestions

Comment: @Wizard It's just the slash that creates your problem, see my answer.

Comment: ok so i got most of the stuff written but i want to know how to combine the two voids that i marked

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the *tmp* folder in your project directory, and pretending the path is: `C:\Project\tmp\`. This file fails to open: `ofstream fout("/tmp/nums.txt");`

The first slash is an error. It's as if you tried to open `C:\Project\\tmp\`.
If you are using Windows, it's like if you changed directory to `C:\Project` in command promt and then used the command `cd \tmp` which would result in:

> The system cannot find the path specified.

Therefore, omit the first slash and let it be: `ofstream fout("tmp/nums.txt");` and it will work.
 (I assume you're including `<fstream>` and that you're using the `namespace std`.)

Comment: @Schemetrical Added more info

Answer (score 0):

there are several issues in your original code:

1) you didn't create any text file to output. Are you trying to output using ">" ?

2) you are generating 49 numbers only. To get 50, you need start from 0 instead 1. (int i=0; )

3) You don't have any delimiter in your output. How do you expect to use them?

change your printFunc to something like this:

```
    ofstream fout ("/tmp/nums.txt");
    if(fout.is_open() ){
       for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
      {
            fout  << arr[i] << std::endl;
      }
```

Comment: you now can fix your problem with the ofstream and generate the output. The other user (program) has to use ifstream to read those numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Include fstream `#include <fstream>`

In printFunc change:

```
ofstream fout("/tmp/nums.txt");
```

to

```
ofstream fout("folder/inner_folder/file.txt", ofstream::out);
```

The second parameter is the mode for the file. `ofstream::out` means write access (which is always set for ofstream objects). 
At the end of the function close the stream like so:

```
fout.close();
```

For reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/ofstream/